# Current Record for the Maximum Number of Ions Trapped in a Paul (Radiofrequency) Trap

Tags: quantum-computer, ion-traps

What is the current known record for the maximum number of ions that have been successfully trapped in a [Paul trap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadrupole_ion_trap)? Could you also share a reference to the scientific article or any form of published research where this achievement has been documented?

Comment: What have you found so far?    350 Ruster et al?

Comment: A nice photo https://alpha.web.cern.ch/sites/default/files/2020-07/PaulTrap_0_0.jpg

Comment: I've found Pogorelov et al with 50 ions. Any reference for the Ruster et al? I don't find it. Nice photo, thanks!

Comment: Why did you tag this "quantum computer"? The record is certainly not for ions which were used for building a quantum computer. You can clearly put many more ions if you require less control.

Comment: Does LHC qualify as a "radiofrequency trap"? I can assure everybody that the number of "ions" in the LHC storage ring is a lot larger than 350. The number of ions trapped in a typical plasma experiment is absolutely monstrous compared to LHC, of course.

Comment: @FlatterMann ... not to mention the sun.

Answer (score 2):

A very quick image search on "ion crystal" led me to https://journals.aps.org/pra/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevA.81.013420, which talks about crystals of 1400 ions in a Paul trap. Not sure this is the record, though.

Update: Searching through the shown related images immediately gave http://arXiv.org/abs/physics/0508125v2, which reports 1700 ions in a Paul trap. (The abstract mentions also ~50000 ions in Penning traps.)

Answer (score 1):

Within the context of quantum technology and atomic physics, the largest number that I am aware of is in the JPL ion trap in space, which "confines a cloud of up to 10^7 ions" [[1](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41586-021-03571-7)]. However, I doubt that this is the actual record, given the constraints of designing for spaceflight.